# Docker stack isn't updating the folder structure with new image

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-container, docker-image

Recently I have changed my dockerfile to use a cleaner folder structure but this isn't being updated in the stack deploy

My folder structure:

```
├── Dockerfile.dev
├── Dockerfile.prod
├── env/
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── services
│   │   └── util
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── version.conf
```

Docker compose file (recorder api part):

```
api-recorder:
    image: img-api-recorder:latest
    build:
      context: ../api-recorder-python/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.${DOCKER_ENV}
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_DIR}api-recorder-python:${WORKDIR}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      PYTHON_ENV: ${DOCKER_ENV}
```

Old Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install kafka-python
RUN pip install python-dotenv
RUN pip install pymongo pymongo[srv]
RUN pip install psycopg2

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo \
    /etc/localtime && \
    echo "America/Sao_Paulo" > /etc/timezone

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-u", "src/main.py"]
```

So what I did was create the `requirements.txt` and changed the COPY command

New Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo \
    /etc/localtime && \
    echo "America/Sao_Paulo" > /etc/timezone

COPY ./src ./

# CMD ["python3", "-u", "main.py"]
CMD ["python3", "-m", "http.server"]
```

The weird thing is that the new `Dockerfile` is being built correctly in a new image because if I run `docker run -it [image_name]:latest bash` and list the directories I receive this:

[image]

which is the new structure made by the new `Dockerfile` on the other hand if I run the stack deploy and enter inside the container I will be in the `/usr/src` path and it will have a wrong structure:

[image]

The content inside the app folder is wrong, it should have the program code inside it
How can I clean it? I already tried delete all the volumes, images, containers, I even reinstalled docker, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: you could check the image that's actually running with `docker ps` to get some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what is happening.

In my `docker-compose` file I was setting a volume that was overwriting my path, this is happening because my `WORKDIR` environment is set to `/usr/src/app` which is the same path that I set in my `dockerfile` but in the `docker-compose` this path is being mirrored to my `api-recorder-python` folder structure

So the only thing that I did was change the volume to `${BASE_DIR}api-recorder-python/src:${WORKDIR}` and I changed my `WORKDIR` to `/usr/src` and all worked fine

Here:

```
api-recorder:
    image: img-api-recorder:latest
    build:
      context: ../api-recorder-python/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.${DOCKER_ENV}
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_DIR}api-recorder-python/src:${WORKDIR}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      PYTHON_ENV: ${DOCKER_ENV}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker compose has both an `image` and `build` section. Precedence is given to the image so that is being used not the build.

You probably want:

```
api-recorder:
    build:
      context: ../api-recorder-python/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.${DOCKER_ENV}
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_DIR}api-recorder-python:${WORKDIR}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      PYTHON_ENV: ${DOCKER_ENV}
```